# Alternative for the storage card driver of the Microsoft Device Emulator

Tags: windows-mobile, emulation, driver, sd-card

We use the Microsoft Device Emulator a lot to develop and to test our mobile applications (VS 2008 SP1, .NET CF 2.0 and 3.5, emulator version 9.0.21022.8). Our projects are started from an emulated storage card mapped to a local folder of the development machine. That way we can deploy, test and debug changes very fast and are not limited by the internal storage space available.

Sadly, the storage card driver seems to be very unstable when accessing a lot of files, throwing random `FileNotFoundException`s and `UnauthorizedAccessException`s when accessing resources located on the shared folder.

The following demonstration code will crash randomly with different values for `i` (from 8 to > 100) with an `UnauthorizedAccessException`. The code won't crash when creating files on the internal storage.

```
private const string PATH = @"\Storage Card\Temp\";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Directory.Exists(PATH))
  {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(PATH);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    using (var stream = File.Create(Path.Combine(PATH, string.Concat(i, ".tmp"))))
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Example:

[image: UnauthorizedAccessException]

I exhaustively searched the web and found some people struggling with the same problem, but didn't find any solution.

What I've already tried:

- Used a FAT32 formatted volume for sharing
- Executed all programs as an administrator
- Drastically reduced the number of files in the shared folder
- Used a RAM disk driver for testing (which works well, but can't be accessed directly from the development machine)
- Increased the RAM of the emulated device to 256 MB
- Tested all the different emulator images available (doesn't change anything)
- Cold or warm booting the emulator devices

My questions are:

- Is there any alternative for the shared folder on the Microsoft Device Emulator?
- Is there a way to fix the behavior of the built-in mechanism (e.g. registry settings)?
- Is there another driver that could be installed on the emulated device to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried monitoring the amount of RAM that is available on the emulator image? My guess would be you are running out of memory in your "device". What are you running in (i.e. VS2008)?

Comment: I'm not running out of RAM (when the sample program crashes, 200 MB are free). Additionally, that wouldn't explain why the programs work on the internal storage of the emulator. I'll add some information about my development environment to the question.